# Compare case insensitive strings then count duplicates

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, text-files, case-insensitive

So I have a text file that looks like this: (first column is the number of repetition, the second column is the data)

```
27 amalyais
17 knc154
14 formulaoneboy
13 mathchallenged31
9 GooGooo1234
8 rkinder
7 tony
7 rammnatt2003
```

My code reads the text file, removes any duplicate, and count how many time the data repeats itself. However, there is data that is in upper case while other data is in lower case. My code right now prints out something like this if such a case ever happens:

```
27 amalyais
12 AMALYAIS
9 Amalyais
```

Is there a way to fix this?
Here is my awk code. I am new to awk so I am still struggling with a lot of things: (temp1 is the text file with duplicated data, temp2 has the output like above)

```
sort -k2 < temp1 |
awk '!z[$1]++{a[$1]=$0;} END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}' |
sort -rn -k1 > temp2
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `tr a-z A-Z` before `awk` might be a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `awk` command you can convert whole record to lowercase before doing any logic like this:

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0)} !z[$2]++{a[$2]=$0;} END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}'
```

However if you include your expected output in question then I can give you more precise answer.